# How to set value 0 instead of empty value as default in woocommerce admin product editor

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, product, price

How can I do this please?
I tried the following code finh here:
[https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104760/woocommerce-how-to-set-product-regular-price-default][1]
but it give me an error: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function.....
I suppose is an old code not working anymore with woocommerce last version
This is the code:

```
    function wpa104760_default_price( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['_regular_price'] ) && trim( $_POST['_regular_price'] ) == '' ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', '0' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wpa104760_default_price' );
```

Thanks

Comment: try `add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wpa104760_default_price',10, 2 );` - Your function take 2 arguments, add_action gives 1 by default.

Comment: Thanks Andy T. you were very kind to answer me. Now it works!
I made an inexperienced mistake, failing to update the code I found. Have a nice day